# Split a string on multiple delimiters and keep them in the output

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have an string that can be 2 to N chars long. I also have 4 ocode (each 2 chars long).

Is there a way to so something like:

```
var tmpArray = inputStr.Split(char1, char2, char3, char4).ToArray();
```

Say that the opcodes are A,B,C,D or 8 and I have this string AB123456789C123412341234B123 the array would be like this:

> A
>
> B
>
> 123456789
>
> C
>
> 123412341234
>
> B
>
> 123

Comment: Maybe use a regex split? Something like `(A|B|C|D|\d*)`?

Comment: Usually when you split you don't include the split character in the output, so what you appear to want to do isn't exactly analogous to `String.Split`.

Comment: @Jonesopolis: Not exactly a dupe for the reason I stated in my other comment. This isn't actually exactly a split.

Comment: @Jonesopolis No that's splitting on a string, not multiple separate characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
private char[] alphabets = {'A','B','C', 'D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};    

var input = "AB123456789C123412341234B123";
var result = input.SplitAndKeep(alphabets).ToList();
```

[image]

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitAndKeep(this string s, char[] delims)
    {
        int start = 0, index;
        while ((index = s.IndexOfAny(delims, start)) != -1)
        {
            if (index - start > 0)
                yield return s.Substring(start, index - start);
            yield return s.Substring(index, 1);
            start = index + 1;
        }
        if (start < s.Length)
        {
            yield return s.Substring(start);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @hbrock I have update my answer, please check it, its tested.

Comment: @hbrock You need to add that number as a character into the array `alphabets`. But I didn't test it yet.

Answer (score 5):

This is all you need.

```
string toSplit = "AB123456789C123412341234B123";
string pattern = @"([ABCD])";
IEnumerable<string> substrings = Regex.Split(toSplit, pattern).Where(i => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i));
```

Test here: http://www.beansoftware.com/Test-Net-Regular-Expressions/Split-String.aspx

All you have to do is declare a character class `[...]` involving all your characters you want to split on, then you encompass that in `(...)` parens to keep the delimiters.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but some explanation would improve it. The key part here is to use the brackets `()` to group. Without the brackets, then the split character is not included in the output.

Comment: Yup thats exactly the thing

Comment: It returns empty strings as well

Answer (score 1):

Use `Regex.Split`

```
var str = "AB123456789C123412341234B123";
Regex r = new Regex(@"([A-Z])|(\d*)");
var parts = r.Split(str).Where(x=> !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray();
```

if you want just A,B,C and D, use this

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"([A-D])|(\d*)");
```

Comment: `()` used for grouping, which is used to return the split parts. The most correct way is `([A-Z])`. For the `[A-D]` you are right.

Comment: I'm just surprised that `(A-Z)` worked like `([A-Z])`.

Answer (score 0):

I find that `Regex` lookahead/lookbehind fits this scenario.  The pattern basically says to split when a single letter is found behind or ahead of the current position.  Then use `Linq` to not return any empty spaces as part of the result, which in this sample case the empty element would be the first element.

[Lookahead/Lookbehind Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string data = "AB123456789C123412341234B123";
        var pieces = Regex.Split(data, "(?<=[a-zA-Z])|(?=[a-zA-Z])").Where(p => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(p));
        foreach (string p in pieces)
            Console.WriteLine(p);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
A
B
123456789
C
123412341234
B
123
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IYu4q0)

Answer (score -1):

Try first splitting on A only. Then split each result on B only. Then split each result on C only etc...

Splitting on A gives you:
`B123456789C123412341234B123`
which you know starts with A

Splitting on B gives you:
`123456789C123412341234`,
`123`
each of which you know starts with B and so on.

Comment: If you think that will work, show a code example that will produce the desired results.

Comment: Actually splitting on A gives you an empty string and `B123456789C123412341234B123` which is how you know there is an A between them. And then splitting on B gives you an empty string, `123456789C123412341234`, and `123` which again is how you know there is a B between each one.  The empty strings are important to determine if the delimiter was there or not.

Comment: What if `A` is at the end?

Comment: @Andrew Then the last item would be an empty string.

Comment: To be clear this is a viable way to solve the problem, but your answer is lacking a lot of details.  And it can be argued that it's an inefficient approach.

Comment: I agree its arguably I bit obscure, but something like this `var v="AB123456789C123412341234B123".Split( 'A').Select( s1 => s1.Split('B').Select( s2 => s2.Split( 'C')).ToArray()).ToArray();` I leave as an exercise in optimisation!